# Coloring based on data density in R

Tags: r, leaflet, heatmap

I have a data frame which every row has a numeric column. I want to allocate different colors based on this column. The numbers of this column range from 1 to 152. I used this function:

```
colors <- function(df,sp) {
check<-colorRampPalette(c("green","red"))(152)
color <- c() 
for (i in 1:nrow(sp))
{
  color <-c(color, check[df$n[df$id==as.numeric(sp[i,]$ID)])
} 
return(color)
}
```

So the color is divided equally into 152 pieces.However, data in this column are mostly small (mostly are 1), the histogram is like this

[image]

If I used this code the color is mostly green-like and hardly see a red-like.

I am using this function to change the line color in the leaflet:

```
leaflet() %>%
...
addPolylines(data = data,weight = '1', color=colors(nodes,data))
```

So how can I change this function to make the color can be evenly distributed, so it can generate more red-like color, not mostly green?

Comment: You could use a logarithm to scale the values.

Comment: If you are willing to use ggplot. This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46389490/3243875

Comment: @MonteCarlo Actually I am using this for the leaflet visualization, so I cannot rescale, sort the data. I have updated the post, do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the function

```
colorQuantile
```

From the library leaflet [colorNumeric](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/2.0.2/topics/colorNumeric). It maps continuous numeric data via the quantile function.

```
colorQuantile(palette, domain, n = 4, probs = seq(0, 1, length.out = n
+ 1), na.color = "#808080", alpha = FALSE, reverse = FALSE,
right = FALSE)
```